# Analyzer project keeping reference to previous analyzer

Tags: visual-studio-2015, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I've created a *brand new* analyzer project which crashes straight away on debug.  It appears to somehow be holding a reference to a previous analyzer that I created.

The analyzers enabled on the project

[image]

The exception, referencing a previous analyzer I created (AnalyzeItEasy). In a completely different folder.

[image]

This is a brand new project and although I'm due an update (I'm on VS 2015 update 1) I wanted to check I'm not going crazy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you build and F5, the extension gets installed into an "experimental instance" of Visual Studio. Unless you do fancy stuff to change that, that's shared for all your projects. F5 the project, and in the Visual Studio that launches, go under Tools > Extensions and Updates, find your other extension, and uninstall it.

Comment: I'll give that a try, I assumed the experimental instance would be new each time rather than shared

Comment: Nope, it's (somewhat confusingly) reused.